# Google Chrome sending a second, 0-length request when visiting a website?

Tags: c++, google-chrome, sockets

I am developing a small and lightweight HTTP Server running on the Nintendo Switch, therefore on a UNIX-like system (freeBSD kernel). I built a HTTP server without any library using the raw `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()`, etc. methods.

I noticed that when I open up the address of the server using Google Chrome, that it first sends a standard HTTP GET request with all headers, and after that a second, 0-byte long request (probably not even a request, it just opens up a second connection to the server, then sends nothing).

Due to my implementation, that's not easy to handle since I receive all data from the connection using `recv()`, which **blocks** until all data is read. Hence, on the second request Chrome sends, it will block "forever" (there is a timeout), because Chrome sends no data.

Is that a known bug to Chrome, and is there any way I could detect and/or prevent this from happening? I tested it with Firefox and Edge and these browsers didn't open a second socket.

Thanks!

Comment: When using HTTP 1.1 or earlier, web browsers tend to make multiple connections to a server so that they can be ready to perform multiple HTTP requests in parallel if needed (that is no longer necessary when using HTTP/2 and later due to multiplexing features, but those are not widely used yet). In the case of Chrome, by default it can have up to 6 connections per hostname.

Comment: Is it really such an issue for your app if you have a timeout implemented? When a new connection is received, and no request is received for a given amount of time (either at the beginning of the connection, or after a response with keep-alive used), just close the connection and move on.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, see my answer on how I fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought. You can just ignore the second socket, and pass `MSG_DONTWAIT` as a flag to the `recv()` call. More on that [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html).

Additionaly, my problem was that I was returning a HTTP 501 response to all requests which had no URL. For the second, 0-length socket, that did obviously break it and made Chrome show an error. I added handling to it wouldn't return an error when there is a 0-length request. It will just silently close it.

Comment: Using `MSG_DONTWAIT` by itself is not a good solution.  What if the connection is viable, but network congestion causes it to lag?  `MSG_DONTWAIT` would cause `recv()` to return *immediately* if there is no data received yet. Using a small timeout, via `setsockopt(SO_RCVTIMEO)` on a blocking socket, or via `select()`/`epoll()`, would be a more robust solution. As for the 501, you shoud not be sending ANY response if no request is received first. And 501 is the wrong reply code to send if a URL does not exist

Comment: Good point. A timeout might be better, even though this is only running on LAN. For the request, I didn't make myself clear enough. 501 was returned if there was any request which was not GET /url, e.g. POST, PATCH, etc. Therefore the 501. I fixed that too :)